# Attribute table blank after exporting from successful Display XY

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.7

I loaded a .csv file into ArcMap 10.7. There are no spaces or weird characters in the field names. The fieldnames are less than 10 characters long. There are no blank fields. I am able to successfully Display XY Data (i.e. ArcMap recognizes the decimal degrees for Latitude and Longitude) and successfully create an Events layer. However, when I go to export the data (i.e., the points I have displayed on the map and can see), the resulting shapefile and attribute table is empty. I have tried selecting all the records and then exporting and I have tried creating a feature class from XY data, to no avail. I have never had this problem before.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Have you perhaps set a processing extent?  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/output-extent.htm

Comment: Did you try to restart your computer ? Sometime it solve some weird ArcMap problem....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did was pulled in the csv file and then exported it out to a dbf. Then I opened it up in excel and exported the dbf to csv. Then pulled that csv in and continued with the display XY and then exported out to shapefile.

You might could try, just copying and pasting text values only in excel into a brand new sheet. That should get rid of everything but the values. Then try displaying XY, then export the XY event out to shapefile. I haven't tried this way, but it could fix the problem also.

I'm thinking that there may have been some type of formula or setting in yours and my csv file. I wasn't about to click through a file with almost 90k rows and about 20 columns to find it.

Hope this works for you as it did for me.